# Generate l3keys meta key from subkey

Tags: latex3, expl3, key-value, l3keys

I’ve created a simple package with options settable via [`l3keys2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3keys2e). I was able to figure out how to make the syntax

```
\usepackage[format = international]{phone}
```

work, but I’d like to make the syntax

```
\usepackage[international]{phone}
```

be a synonym. The method I’m using in the code below works, but is very repetitive, especially when I’ve got more formatting options. Is there a simpler way?

Here’s the code:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3, l3keys2e, xparse}
\ProvidesExplPackage
    {phone}{2013/06/19}{0.1}{Format phone numbers}

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \phone_international_fmt:NNN  #1#2#3
  { +1 - #1 - #2 - #3 }

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \phone_parendash_fmt:NNN  #1#2#3
  { (#1) \nobreakspace #2 - #3 }

\keys_define:nn { phone }
  {
    format .choice_code:n =
      {
        \cs_new_eq:Nc \phone_fmt:NNN 
          { phone_ \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl _fmt:NNN }
      },
    format .generate_choices:n =
      {
        international,
        parendash,
      },
% These next lines will become repetitive if I have many more formatting options
    international .meta:n = { format = international },
    parendash     .meta:n = { format = parendash     },
  }

\ProcessKeysOptions { phone }

\NewDocumentCommand \phone
  { >{ \SplitArgument {2} {-} } m }
  { \phone_fmt:NNN #1 }

\endinput
```

A minimal example using this package looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[parendash]{phone}
\usepackage[format = parendash]{phone}

\begin{document}

\phone{212-555-1212}

\end{document}
```

This yields the desired result

> (212) 555-1212

Comment: I’m not at all certain I’ve got the nomenclature correct; feel free to rename this question to fix this.

Comment: Aside: `\cs_new_nopar:Npn \phone_international_fmt:NNN` isn't really encouraged, and I'd suggest `\cs_new:Npn \phone_international_fmt:NNN` instead. Apart from a few specific  internals, we've standardised on a position that functions with arguments should be 'long'.

Comment: Shouldn't the `:NNN` argument spec rather be `:nnn`?

Comment: @cgnieder Yes; in that code all the `:NNN` should be `:nnn`

Comment: @JosephWright, is that the case, even though xparse defaults to short arguments?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon Yes, as `xparse` is a different thing. At the _document_ level it's most sensible to be restrictive as standard (most document commands don't make sense for multiple paragraphs), but at the code level this is different. A reasonable number of LaTeX bugs were caused by internal code not accepting `\par` tokens.

Comment: @JosephWright, but in this particular case the semantics *do* imply that `\par` tokens should be forbidden. But now I’ll make that choice intentionally, and know what the default should be; thanks.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon Unless you control the input at the code level (for example an auxiliary), the risk of a warning about a `\par` token from an internal function is really not worth it. Much better to pick up at the document level and know that at the code level everything is 'long'.

Comment: @JosephWright The `xparse`-generated function `\phone` is the only thing that calls these internal functions; is that insufficient? Or is allowing long arguments just that much safer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an `unknown` key handler for this whereby you pass any unknown key back into the system as `format = <unknown key>` (a similar system is used by TikZ to recognise colours and node shapes).  Here's an example which uses that.  It gives a warning if there isn't a corresponding format.

I have to use a helper command to feed the unknown key back into the key handler since if I just did `format / unknown .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { phone} { format = #1 } }` then the `#1` would be `\l_keys_key_tl` and L3 would be extremely careful and *not* expand the `\l_keys_key_tl` until the last minute, by which time it would have changed its value from the unknown key to `format`.  The helper macro allows me to use the value of `\l_keys_key_tl` instead of the token list variable.

I also fixed the `NNN` to `nnn`.  Because I wanted to set a default, the setter inside the key handler is now `\cs_set_eq:Nc` instead of `\cs_new_eq:Nc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120102/86}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{phone.sty}
\RequirePackage{expl3, l3keys2e, xparse}
\ProvidesExplPackage
    {phone}{2013/06/19}{0.1}{Format phone numbers}

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \phone_international_fmt:nnn  #1#2#3
  { +1 - #1 - #2 - #3 }

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \phone_parendash_fmt:nnn  #1#2#3
  { (#1) \nobreakspace #2 - #3 }

% Set a default
\cs_set_eq:NN \phone_fmt:nnn \phone_parendash_fmt:nnn

\msg_new:nnnn {phone} {no~ format} {Format~ `#1'~ is~ not~ recognised~ by~ this~ package,~ using~ the~ default~ `parendash'~ instead.} {}

\keys_define:nn { phone }
  {
    format .choice:,
    format .choice_code:n =
      {
        \cs_set_eq:Nc \phone_fmt:nnn 
        { phone_ \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl _fmt:nnn }
      },
    format .generate_choices:n =
      {
        international,
        parendash,
      },
      format / unknown .code:n = {
        \msg_warning:nnn {phone} {no~ format} {#1}
      },
    unknown .code:n = {
      \phone_unknown_key:V \l_keys_key_tl
    },
  }

\cs_new:Npn \phone_unknown_key:n #1
{
  \keys_set:nn { phone} { format = #1 }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \phone_unknown_key:n {V}


\ProcessKeysOptions { phone }

\NewDocumentCommand \phone
  { >{ \SplitArgument {2} {-} } m }
  { \phone_fmt:nnn #1 }

\endinput
\end{filecontents}
 \usepackage[british]{phone}

\begin{document}

\phone{212-555-1212}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answers the question I asked, hence the upvote and acceptance. As it happens, the actual package has multiple keys for which I want the values as shortcuts, so I’ll actually be using Joseph’s solution.

Answer (score 8):

The approach you've taken looks correct. Internally, the `.meta:n` property is creating a standard key which is more-or-less equivalent to

```
key-name-1 .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { module } { key-name-2 = #1 } }
```

If you have a large number of these meta keys to create, you might want to use a comma-list mapping

```
\clist_map_inline:nn { key-one , key-two , key-three ... }
  { \keys_define:nn { mymodule } { #1 .meta:n = { format = #1 } }
```

but for just a couple this is probably making your code more not less complex.

Comment: Considering that I’ll also be adding `.value_forbidden:` for each of these shortcuts, the benefit starts to outweigh the cost very quickly.