# Patch font with LuaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, latin-modern

I don’t like the spacing of `\textperiodcentered` = U+00B7 in the OpenType cut of Latin Modern. Different from Computer Modern—and in fact, from just about any font I have on my system—LM gives the character fairly wide sidebearings. I think it’s a bug, anyway, and have so reported it to the Bogusław Jackowski *et al.* at [GUST](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry#Fonts).

But while I wait for Jacko to fix this, can LuaTeX font patching (see, *e.g.*, *[non-invasive kerning/spacing modification: what options are there?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118624/2966)*) be used to adjust the sidebearings of this character at run-time?
How would such patching be implemented?

(By experimentation, I determined that a kern of −0.25em on either side of the dot gives it the same spacing as the period “.”, so that’s the amount I’d want to shave off the glyph’s bounding box.)

---

The code below illustrates the issue. In my actual code, I’m using the Unicode MIDDLE DOT (U+00B7) “·”, and its use is within a macro whose definition is copied (via `\cs_set_eq:`) to another, so neither redefining `\textperiodcentered` nor `\newunicodechar` can directly help. (This *is* a problem with my code, and one which I’ll be fixing; the question above is still interesting to me.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifot\ottrue
\ifot
  \usepackage{fontspec} % uses LM OpenType
\fi
\begin{document}
\ifot LMRoman OTF: \else Computer Modern: \fi
800\textperiodcentered 555\textperiodcentered 1212
\end{document}
```

The results from two separate runs (first with `\ottrue`, next with `\otfalse`) are these:

[image: LM spacing bug demonstrated]

The Computer Modern version is typographically correct, or at least is similar to the result using any other font.  Try to render the text “800·555·1212” (using U+00B7 “·”) in any application, comparing LMRoman to other fonts; rarely does it have such wide sidebearings. (The Lucida fonts, *e.g.*, the one used on this website, are the others where I’ve seen this.)

Comment: Please augment your code snippets so that they become a self-contained, compilable example. Incidentally, what happens if you provide an explicit `\setmainfont` instruction?

Comment: @Mico, no difference; the extra ¼em on either side of the midpoint “·” is built-in to the OT version of Latin Modern.

Comment: BTW, Jacko has confirmed that this *is* a bug, the LM team having incorrectly assumed that U+00B7 was a math operator; but fixing this bug will change font metrics in a backwards-incompatible way—which may yet happen, but not anytime soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118626/7674), the following feature file should do what you want:

```
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
feature kern {
    pos periodcentered <-250 0 -500 0> ;
} kern;
```

(According to the [spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_feature_file_syntax.html#2.e.iv), the values in the angle brackets mean x placement, y placement, x advance and y advance, in that order, given in design units aka. `em`.)

You would load the feature file (lets call it `LMRoman.fea`) with:

```
\setmainfont[FeatureFile=LMRoman.fea]{Latin Modern Roman}
```

Answer (score 7):

You get the same spacing with the type1 lmodern if you use the real char with the help of textcomp:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % uses LM Type1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
800\textperiodcentered 555\textperiodcentered 1212
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. The LM Type1 font has U+00B7, and the character in the type1 font can displayed as the OpenType version. For example:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \begin{document}
   800\char189 555\char189 1212
   \end{document}
   ```
2. The command `\textperiodcentered` act as `\cdot` in text mode. And these two command are mapping to the same character.

   ```
   % filename: test.tex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \pagestyle{empty}
   \begin{document}
   \textperiodcentered$\cdot$
   \end{document}
   ```

   Using `pdffonts test.pdf` getting the font's info in the PDF output:

   ```
   name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
   ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
   SQTJQN+LMMathSymbols10-Regular       Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
   ```
3. So, this is not a bug of font, and is a bug of character mapping.

Answer (score 5):

Let's do some experiments with `texdef`:

```
> texdef -t latex textperiodcentered

\textperiodcentered:
macro:->\OMS-cmd \textperiodcentered \OMS\textperiodcentered

> texdef -t latex -p textcomp textperiodcentered

\textperiodcentered:
macro:->\TS1-cmd \textperiodcentered \TS1\textperiodcentered
```

What does this mean? Let's go slowly. A command such as `\<dENC>-cmd` where `<dENC>` is the uppercase name of a known encoding, checks to see if the command `<cENC><arg>` is defined, where `<cENC>` is the current encoding and `<arg>` is the first token after `\<dENC>-cmd` (“d” for ”default”). If it is, then `<cENC><arg>` is used, otherwise `<dENC><arg>` is used.

Example (I'll skip over inessential details). LaTeX sees `\textperiodcentered` and expands it into

```
\OMS-cmd \textperiodcentered \OMS\textperiodcentered
```

If the current encoding is `OT1` (as in your `\otfalse` setting), LaTeX tries to see whether `\OT1\textperiodcentered` (it's an impossible command to issue without some tricks, the inner backslash is part of the name) is defined, which it isn't. So the “default branch” is followed, which amounts to do

```
{\fontencoding{OMS}\selectfont \OMS\textperiodcentered}
```

and so printing `\char"1` from the font associated to the OMS encoding, usually the math symbols font, where it has no sidebearings that in math are added automatically.

If the current encoding is `EU1` (as in your `\ottrue` setting), the check for definedness of `\EU1\textperiodcentered` succeeds, so what's done is simply

```
\EU1\textperiodcentered
```

without any unnecessary grouping, which prints `\char"00B7` in the current font. This glyph has sidebearings by choice of the font designers.

What `textcomp` does is to change the default encoding associated to `\textperiodcentered` to `TS1`, but the effect is similar; only difference is that a character from the text companion font will be used by default.

If you want to change the working of `\textperiodcentered`, it's sufficient to modify its definition for the `EU1` (XeLaTeX) or `EU2` (LuaLaTeX) encoding. The macro `\encodingdefault` will expand to the correct one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareTextCommand{\textperiodcentered}{\encodingdefault}{\kern-.25em\char"00B7\kern-.25em }%
}
\begin{document}

800\textperiodcentered 555\textperiodcentered 1212
\end{document}
```

[image]

In conclusion it's definitely not a bug, but expected behavior. OpenType fonts can have a “U+2E31 WORD SEPARATOR MIDDLE DOT” character, which has no side bearings (not Latin Modern OT, I'm afraid).

---

Other fonts have a less spaced centered period; a good guess seems to be a width of 0.25em, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\periodsep}{}{\makebox[.25em]{\symbol{"00B7}}}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\test}{800\periodsep 555\periodsep 1212\par
800\symbol{"00B7}555\symbol{"00B7}1212\par\medskip}

\test

\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}\test

\fontspec{TeX Gyre Termes}\test

\fontspec{TeX Gyre Pagella}\test
\end{document}
```

If your application doesn't directly use the character, but generates it via a macro, this seems to be the best approach.

[image]

Alternatively, you could accept any width for the centered period unless it's over a fixed threshold, by changing the definition of `\periodsep` to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\periodsep}{}
 {%
  \ifdim\fontcharwd\font"00B7>.3em % threshold value
    \makebox[.25em]{\symbol{"00B7}}%
  \else
    \symbol{"00B7}%
  \fi
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In the actual file, I was using U+00B7 “·” within a macro which a second name is `\cs_set_eq:` to (see the basic idea in my question [_Generate l3keys meta key from subkey_](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120102/2966)) so I can’t directly use your suggestion, though.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon I don't see why you can't.

Comment: It _can_ work if I use `\newunicodechar{·}{\textperiodcentered}` _before_ defining the macro that uses the middle-dot character. But that’s only needed for Latin Modern, and I haven’t checked the package font options at the time I’m setting the phone-number-formatting options. See https://gist.github.com/jcsalomon/5921380

Comment: @J.C.Salomon I've added something about your real problem.